# Subgroups of $\mathbb Z \times(\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z)$

Tags: abstract-algebra

So I am dealing with a problem from Dummit (specifically 2.1.7) and am having some issues. The  part of the problem in question is:

> Prove the set of elements of the direct product $\mathbb{Z} \times (\mathbb{Z} / n \mathbb{Z})$ of infinite order together with the identity is not a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z} \times (\mathbb{Z} / n \mathbb{Z})$.

I am assuming this question is referring to addition as the binary operation for both sets. I know the proof basically involves showing that the product is not closed; however, do not all the elements of the integers have infinite order (except the identity)? In that case, the elements of infinite order together with the identity would form all of $\mathbb{Z} \times (\mathbb{Z} / n \mathbb{Z})$ would it not?

Thanks

Comment: The answer to your last question:  The element $(0,a)\in \mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ has finite order, but is not the identity unless $a$ is.

Comment: Well this is embarrassing, I cannot believe I overlooked such a simple thing. Thanks guys.

Comment: @KFGauss Just FYI, if one of the answers settles your question satisfactorily you are encouraged to "accept" the answer. To do this, click on the grey check-mark to the left of it, which will then turn green. This rewards the user who answered your question and shows other users that the question has been answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the elements $(1,[ 1])$ and $(-1, [ 0])$; they each have infinite order but their sum has finite order and is not the identity.

Comment: You need $n>2$ for this to work.

Comment: I see that now, thank you. I have changed it.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: $\langle 1,1\rangle$ and $\langle -1,0\rangle$ both have infinite order.