# Torsion subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}\times \left( \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\right)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, torsion-groups

An exercise from Dummit and Foote, example 2.1.7

Fix some $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ with $n>1$.  Find the torsion subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}\times \left( \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\right)$.  Show that the set of elements of infinite order together with the identity is $\textit{not}$ a subgroup of this direct product.

My work;

The elements in $G=\mathbb{Z}\times \left( \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\right)$ are $(x,\overline{y}), x\in \mathbb{Z}, \bar{y}\in (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$.  The only element in $\mathbb{Z}$ that has finite order is the element $1_{\mathbb{Z}}=0$, but all elements of $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$ have finite order.  Thus, elements in $H=\{(x,\overline{y})\in \mathbb{Z}\times \left( \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\right) \mid |(x,\overline{y})|<\infty \}$ are of the form $(0,\bar{y})$, and it is clear now that $H$ is nonempty.  As inverse elements of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ are $-\overline{y}$, then for $\overline{x}, \overline{y}\in \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, 
$$(0,\overline{x})+(0,\overline{y})^{-1}=(0,\overline{x})+(0,-\overline{y})=(0,\overline{x}-\overline{y})=(0,\overline{x-y})\in \mathbb{Z}\times \left( \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\right)$$  So since $(0,\overline{x-y})$ is in $H$, $H$ is a subgroup of $G$.

So that seems pretty straight forward.  Then infinite ordered elements would be of the form $(x,\overline{y})$ where $x\neq 0$.  Combining this with $1_{G}=(0,\overline{0})$, we check to see if this set is a subgroup.  But closure fails because for elements $(1,\overline{1}), (-1,\overline{1})$,

$$(1,\overline{1})+(-1,\overline{1})=(1-1,\overline{1}+\overline{1})=(0,\overline{2})$$

which is not of infinite order.  So this subset of $G$ is not closed and thus can not be a subgroup of $G$.

Does this proof suffice?

Comment: Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/198160/subgroups-of-mathbb-z-times-mathbb-z-n-mathbb-z

Comment: The group law on $\mathbf Z\times\mathbf Z/n\mathbf Z$ is *not* mutiplication, but addition. Why do you denote it multiplicatively?

Comment: Up to notations as pointed out by Bernard, it is perfect.

Comment: I was just using the notation as $xy$ but I know its addition.  I will change.  Thank you guys.